# Django log info as well as error logs on production

Tags: python, django, logging, django-logging

I am trying to log INFO as well as ERROR log on production.
But I am not sure how to mention both log levels for the same project.

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'root': {
        'level': 'WARNING',
        'handlers': ['console', ],
    },
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s '
                      '%(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        },
        'sns': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'project.abc.snshandler.SNSHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose'

        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.db.backends': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'handlers': ['console', ],
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'django.security.DisallowedHost': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'handlers': ['console', ],
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'project': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'handlers': ['console', 'sns'],
            'propagate': False,
        },

    },
}
```

At project level i want to log INFO logs as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logging level you specify in your configuration is the **minimum** level will be logged. Just to recap, here the predefined levels in order of importance (from lowest to maximum):

- `DEBUG`
- `INFO`
- `WARNING`
- `ERROR`
- `CRITICAL`

So, if you put `INFO` in your configuration you will see all logs marked as `INFO`, `WARNING`, `ERROR`, and `CRITICAL`.

If you really want to see **only** `INFO` and `ERROR` you can try to write some custom code, but I discourage it as it smells as a bad design.

*References*:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html?highlight=logging#module-logging

#### Edit

Here how your configuration would look like:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'root': {
        'level': 'WARNING',
        'handlers': ['console', ],
    },
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s '
                      '%(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        },
        'sns': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'project.abc.snshandler.SNSHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose'

        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.db.backends': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'handlers': ['console', ],
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'django.security.DisallowedHost': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'handlers': ['console', ],
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'project': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'handlers': ['console', 'sns'],
            'propagate': False,
        },

    },
}
```

Comment: Here I don't want INFO logs to get notified by SNS. Only ERROR logs should get notified by SNS.

Comment: I see. So set `INFO` in `console` and `ERROR` in `sns`. I updated my suggested configuration code.

Comment: to clarify my edit: all logs from `project` of level `INFO` and above are handled by both `sns` and `console`, but `sns` discards all logs that are not `ERROR` or above.